# JQuery, expect Object.prototype.toString.call($aDiv) to return "object Array", but "object Object" is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and is currently learning how to create new html elements using jquery.

I came up with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $aDiv = jQuery('<div>hello</div>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I played around with the newly created `div` in chrome console.

[image]

When I run `$aDiv`, an array that contain one element is returned (I think an array is returned because it is surrounded by square bracket). However, when I run `Object.prototype.toString.call($aDiv)`, I was expecting `object Array` to be returned, yet what actually is returned is `object Object`.

Am I missing something? Or is my understanding somewhat incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery object is an **array-like** object not an **array**. An array like object is any object that has a `length` property and has (though not necessarly) properties from `0` to `length - 1`.

In the image you posted of the console log, you can clearly see that the `__proto__` property of the jQuery object is in fact `Object` not `Array`.

The console tends (though not always) to log array-like objects in the same way as arrays, because for most of the time those objects are used exactly like arrays. Other notable objects that get loged in the form of arrays even though they're not are:

- `HTMLCollection`s: Try `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));`.
- `NodeList`s: Try `console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div"));`.
- ...

**Example of an array-like object:**

the following object:

```
{
    0: "Hello, world!",
    length: 1
}
```

is an array-like object.

Comment: hi ibrahim, thank you for the answer. Do you mind if I ask, why when I run `$aDiv`, an object with array syntax (i.e. square bracket) is returned? I think this is where I'm tripped up

Comment: chrome might just present it that way.

Comment: @Thor I've also added some other array-like objects that get loged in the form of arrays.

Comment: Thanks ibrahim! the edit did make things clearer. Thanks again for helping out! :)

Comment: @Thor You're welcome! I too had this confusion once. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery returns an array-like object, but it's not an array. [Notice in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/) it returns a [`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

Comment: hi Daniel, thank you for pointing me to the documentation. Will definitly read it through :)